# Meaning of "Supply Voltage: 3~132V" on an electric drive system plate?

Tags: voltage, motor, ratings, drive

I have an electric drive system for a garage door that has the supply voltage mentioned above. What does the 3~132V mean?. The output torque is 190 NM and the output speed is 85 rpm. The input current rating is 13.3 A.
Here's the best photo I have of the plate:
[image]

Comment: Is it 3-phase or is it missing some digits. Post an in-focus, properly cropped photo of the rating plate and the wires or terminals.

Comment: 3 phase 132V...

Comment: 3-phase garage door opener gotta be a heck of a garage door opener.  Like an industrial sized door you drive tractor trailers through.  Is that the case???

Comment: Maybe it's the max current input when the motor starts, as 190NM and 85rpm (prob gearbox) aren't that high. 3-phase could make sense for an old motor.

Comment: @KyleB, It is a parking garage door for an office building.

Comment: Elektromat is still in business.   They don't have this model listed on their website, but I did find it at some distributors.  If you contact Elektromat directly, they almost certainly will provide you with the technical data for this unit.   Here's their current similar products  https://gfa-elektromaten.com/en-DE/products_SI.html#ELEKTROMATEN_SI

Comment: 3~ almost certainly indicates 3phase.

Comment: Now that there is a picture of the name plate (or label) it seems like it is not such a bad question that it would need to be closed. IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's cross check everything.

Output speed in rad/sec:

85 RPM * 1m/60s * 2 * pi rad/rev = 8.9 rad/sec.

Output torque: 190 Nm.

Output power: 190 * 8.9 = 1.7kW

Input power (assuming it is three-phase):

132 * 13.3 * sqrt(3) = 3kW. Or, maybe we should say 3kVA.

Considering that the input frequency is 60 Hz and the output is 85 RPM, it is safe to say that there is a high ratio mechanical gear reduction integrated in the motor. Between that and motor efficiency and power factor, this ratio between input kVA and output kW sounds about right. So I would bet money that it is a three phase 132V motor.